# Is glm::perspective's fov parameter defined as half the angle of the field of view?

Tags: c++, opengl, rendering, glm-math, perspectivecamera

I'm at the optimization phase of a renderer I've been writing in OpenGL, and my next step is to cull everything I can't see. When reading [this](https://www.scratchapixel.com/lessons/3d-basic-rendering/perspective-and-orthographic-projection-matrix/building-basic-perspective-projection-matrix) and other resources, I see the visual depiction of the frustum like:

[image: Frustum]

*Image from: https://www.scratchapixel.com/images/upload/perspective-matrix/camsetup1.png*

And therefore thought that we pass something like `glm::radians(90.0f)`. However I started running into culling problems with my algorithm because I thought that I'd be going 45 degrees along the left and right for the planes... but then I started getting false-positive culling. As soon as I changed it to using the `fov` angle passed to `glm::perspective` then culling starts working fine.

However there's two things I'm unsure about:

1. Is what I said correct? As in the fov value should be half of the green angle in the image posted above?
2. If (1) is true then why does a fov of 90 not show me everything to my left and right?

These are important for me to understand because I want to make my culling algorithms cull as much as possible without false positives. As you may be able to guess, I was getting false positive culls because I thought "I need to divide the first argument I use for `glm::perspective()` again by two to get half of the angle" which caused a tighter frustum that would cull a lot more than it should have.

The way I'm culling currently is to calculate the left and right edges of the frustum and culling any 2D lines that can't be seen by the left or the right edges (as if they were line segments) through dot products. This is why a narrower angle was giving me grief. As an aside, if there is a better way of doing this let me know, though I figure two dot products is probably the cheapest I'm going to get with respect to efficiency of calculations for a line I have to check.

Comment: *"Is what I said correct? As in the fov value should be half of the green angle in the image posted above?"* - No, when you use [`glm::perspective`](https://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.9/api/a00665.html#ga747c8cf99458663dd7ad1bb3a2f07787), then the angle is the full angle, but it is the angle form the top to the bottom of the frustum. So the angle from the left to the right depends  on the aspect ration. So if the width of the view is grater than the height and `fov` is less than 180°, the angle for the left to the right is greater than the angle from the top to the bottom.

Comment: Furthermore, it is the vertical angle. Btw, it is usually easier and more robust to [extract the planes from the view-projection matrix](http://www.cs.otago.ac.nz/postgrads/alexis/planeExtraction.pdf).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `fov` parameter of [`glm::perspective`](https://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.9/api/a00665.html#ga747c8cf99458663dd7ad1bb3a2f07787) is the angle from the bottom to the top (*y* axis) of the view frustum.
If the view  port is rectangular and the width of the viewport is greater then the height (and `fov` < 180°), then the angle from the left to the right is greater than the angle from the top to the bottom:

```cpp
aspect = width / height
fov_x  = atan(tan(fov_y/2) * aspect) * 2
```